# Standard pattern in Meteor for searching and displaying documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, search, meteor

Say I have a Meteor site where I want a function to search for a document in a collection and display it to the user.

This collection is very large and is not feasible to keep all on the client.

I have a publish statement that specifies what documents need to be pushed to the user.

```
Meteor.publish('listing', function (search) {

    return TestObjs.find({"name": search });

});
```

And I have a search input textbox which when it changes I'd like to subscribe to the publication to get the records that I need.

```
'change #searchText' : function(e,t){
    Session.set("searchTerm", $("#searchText").val());
    Meteor.subscribe("listing", $("#searchText").val());

}
```

So every time I search for text, client is getting sent the documents it needs to be displayed.

The problem is, the subscribe call doesn't delete any old documents from the client for previous search terms. So the first problem is the more the user uses the search function, the more documents are going to be stored on the client. Secondly, if I want to display the search results for the current search term, I cannot just go

```
Template.home.helpers({
    listOfObjs: function () {
        return TestObjs.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

This will return all record on the client which would be all records that match the current and any previous search term.

I have to replicate the publish statement

```
Template.home.helpers({
    listOfObjs: function () {
        return TestObjs.find({"name": Session.get("searchTerm") }).fetch();
    }
});
```

This works, but I'm essentially duplicating the logic in multiple places. This is just a simple example but what if my search algorithm was more complicated with paging etc.

So I was wondering, what is the recommended Meteor way to return search results for collections that sit on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Answer without try. Hope you looking for this.

```
    var list;
    'change #searchText' : function(e,t){
        Session.set("searchTerm", $("#searchText").val());

        if (list)
          list.stop();

        list = Meteor.subscribe("listing", $("#searchText").val());

    }
```

From the [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe)

`stop()` Cancel the subscription. This will typically result in the server directing the client to remove the subscription's data from the client's cache.

Comment: Yes this would solve the first problem of the old search results clogging up the client side. However, you probably should still duplicate the logic when displaying the search results because you cannot be sure that this is the only subscription that returns testObj.